# How to configure default table columns in awesone_nested_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, awesome-nested-set

Awesome_nested_set gem comes with default columns

```
:parent_id
:lft
:right
```

How can I configure them that is use different names for them.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`awesome_nested_set` gem `README`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set):

> You can pass various options to `acts_as_nested_set` macro. Configuration options are:
>
> - `parent_column`: specifies the column name to use for keeping the
>     position integer (default: parent_id)
> - `left_column`: column name for left boundary data (default: lft)
> - `right_column`: column name for right
>     boundary data (default: rgt)